# The link for review queue is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I was trying out the new top bar and noticed that, the link for review queue is pointing at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits right now which should be https://stackoverflow.com/review. It seems to have the right title but its pointing at the wrong spot.

[image]

Is it just me or this one went unnoticed? This is the case for both meta.SO and SO.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @Stijn It might be a rep-based issue. At 575 rep, I can reproduce this.

Comment: Anyone know what that little icon is supposed to be? I haven't the slightest clue… How did you even know it was supposed to be "review"?

Comment: Can reproduce. Something that says "review queues" should not link to a specific queue, which the user may even not have access to in the first place due to rep. levels. The "Suggesed edits" queue needs 2k rep. to view it, thus anyone with < 2k gets the "You need...:" message. Oh, and @CodyGray - it has a hover tooltip.

Comment: I have the same issue, and I have 1,400 Rep

Comment: @CodyGray Because of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Z4v.png)

Comment: Yeah I have the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue on the main site and meta. When I inspect the element I see it is pointing to the suggested edit queue. href="/review/suggested-edits"

Comment: I am also being taken to suggested-edits, though I rarely do those, preferring close/reopen queues instead. So this adds two extra clicks for me. Since people are mentioning rep, I am at 7,414 at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps a < 10k problem? That is my next privilege tier, nothing else in between for me. Everyone commenting here that can repro is < 10k, while the one person who cannot is > 10k.

Comment: We used to have two links to review queues - one was the highlight for pending suggested edits linking to that queue (and that for 10k+ users was replaced with a count of pending review items and a link to /review), the other was a direct link to the review queues for people with access to them. We lost that direct link in the new design, but kept the former logic. We are still figuring out what is the right thing to do here (what number to display, and where to link).

Comment: 609 Rep, can confirm I get suggested-edits on both SO and MSO. This is definitely a bug and should be fixed @Oded

Comment: Same issue (1001 Rep, SO and MSO). Fixed it by changing the href of the button from "/review/suggested-edits" to "/review". But this is not really a nice, long-term solution...

Comment: It seems like the issue has been solved!

Comment: Marking this [tag:status-completed] as the link now points to the correct page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Undo ♦'s comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343100/the-link-for-review-queue-is-broken#comment445287_343100):

> Marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as the link now points to the
>   correct page.

This bug has been fixed.

Comment: But for those of us who want a link to edit - that functionality has gone!