# Should the "Review Queues" count in the top bar show just suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, top-bar

Since the "Review Queues" button [has been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343100/the-link-for-review-queue-is-broken) to link to the [Review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) instead of the [suggested edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/), I don't think it makes sense for the number to show just the number of items in the suggested edits queue. Wouldn't it make more sense to show the total number of items in all review queues? Or even to not show the number at all?

What do you think?

Comment: Probably pointless to be honest. If you have high enough rep this would always be a high number. Not sure what to show however I'm happy just clicking to see if anything needs reviewing.

Comment: @Bugs You are probably right. But since the review button and suggested edits button have been combined, I'm now wondering if it even makes sense to have a number there at all.

Answer (score 9):

Not my idea, but...

[image: infinity]

...if we could just show that when there are new items in the queue, with a drop-down to view the actual *counts*... That would probably do more good than trying to keep an accurate number.

**Update:** see ["posts awaiting review" orange counter is way off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653)

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but maybe tweak it so that the entire icon glows blue when there's something in the queue, but is gray otherwise. An infinite number of items, while perhaps accurate, is rather discouraging...

Comment: Yes - I'm in the camp that the number popping up is distracting (and very likely inaccurate).  If the object of the new toolbar is to push people to use the new left side links, drawing your eye almost all the way to the right seems to counteract that initiative.