# Clicking on the review icon takes me to a list of review queues, not edits to review (as it used to)

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar

In the past, if I clicked on the numbered review link i.e.

[image]

I was taken to questions that needed reviewing. e.g.

[image]

Now I'm taken to the standard review lists. e.g.

[image]

This does not seem browser specific.

Is it a bug? It's certainly less convenient for reviewers.

**Update**

This issue is closely related to [The link for review queue is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343100/the-link-for-review-queue-is-broken) . It appears to me that there are two groups of users expecting a link in this position, but only one link.

The problem at the moment, is that the link seems to be the worse of both problems - that is, it is showing the number of outstanding edits requiring review, but on clicking takes you to /reviews rather than the page to allow reviewers to address those outstanding edits.

I think two links are required as @Oded has suggested in [The link for review queue is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343100/the-link-for-review-queue-is-broken).

Comment: When hovering the review icon, what for address do you see at the bottom of the browser? For me, it works fine on all browsers that I have on my PC. It all points to the SO/review page

Comment: To clarify: I'm taken to http://stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: Perhaps you were experiencing this bug in the new top-bar, which was recently fixed? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343100/the-link-for-review-queue-is-broken

Comment: No, I'm still getting the same behaviour. I'm on a different laptop now - though still Linux (Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit) and Chrome (56.0.2924.87 64-bit)

Comment: @DanLowe No it's the opposite - it seems to me that that "fix" has actually caused the problem!

Answer (score 1):

After a while of playing with this, I think I actually prefer the way this button now works. Suggested edits are the third option down on the `review` page, and this view gives me direct access to more than I had before.

The "fix" is to get used to the new system - it gives many more options than previously, for the cost of an extra click.

Comment: I disagree. I don't want to suffer excess clicks when I'm trying to help the stackoverflow community. I want the link to take me directly to where I can help,  as it used to.